# SUM element-wise values of Python dict based on another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list

```
mylist=[('B',), ('D',), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'J'), ('B', 'P'), ('B', 'M'), ('D', 'J'), ('D', 'P'), ('D', 'M'), ('J', 'P'), ('J', 'M'), ('P', 'M'), ('B', 'D', 'J'), ('B', 'D', 'P'), ('B', 'D', 'M')]

dict={'B': [1, 0, 1, 1], 'D': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'J': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'P': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'M': [1, 0, 0, 1]}
```

what i was trying to do is to sum up the dictionary value based on the list.  My code is:

```
myresult=[]
for k,v in dict.items():
        row=sum(v for k, v in dict.items() if k in mylist) 
        myresult.append(row)
```

What i got was `[0,0,0,0,0]`

The intended result was to sum individual items from dictionary based on mylist and return something like

```
[(1,0,1,1), (1,1,0,1), (2,1,1,2), xxxx]
```

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist=[('B',), ('D',), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'J'), ('B', 'P'), ('B', 'M'), ('D', 'J'), ('D', 'P'), ('D', 'M'), ('J', 'P'), ('J', 'M'), ('P', 'M'), ('B', 'D', 'J'), ('B', 'D', 'P'), ('B', 'D', 'M')]

# change dict to dict_map
dict_map={'B': [1, 0, 1, 1], 'D': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'J': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'P': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'M': [1, 0, 0, 1]}

myresult = []
for item in mylist:
    arrays = [dict_map.get(i) for i in item]
    sum_list = [sum(x) for x in zip(*arrays)]
    myresult.append(sum_list)
    print(sum_list)
```

result:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 0, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi will change, thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach using functional programming:

```
from functools import reduce

my_list = [('B',), ('D',), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'J'), ('B', 'P'), ('B', 'M'), ('D', 'J'), ('D', 'P'), ('D', 'M'),
           ('J', 'P'), ('J', 'M'), ('P', 'M'), ('B', 'D', 'J'), ('B', 'D', 'P'), ('B', 'D', 'M')]

dic = {'B': [1, 0, 1, 1], 'D': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'J': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'P': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'M': [1, 0, 0, 1]}


def element_wise_sum(l, o):
    return [a + b for a, b in zip(l, o)]


res = [reduce(element_wise_sum, [dic[label] for label in labels]) for labels in my_list]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple for loop to iterate the main list and get keys and sums using list comprehension like this way,

```
mylist=[('B',), ('D',), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'J'), ('B', 'P'), ('B', 'M'), ('D', 'J'), ('D', 'P'), ('D', 'M'), ('J', 'P'), ('J', 'M'), ('P', 'M'), ('B', 'D', 'J'), ('B', 'D', 'P'), ('B', 'D', 'M')]

dict={'B': [1, 0, 1, 1], 'D': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'J': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'P': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'M': [1, 0, 0, 1]}

myresult = []
for i in mylist:
    keys = [dict.get(j) for j in i]
    summation = [sum(x) for x in zip(*keys)]
    myresult.append(tuple(summation))
print(myresult)
```

**Sample:** https://rextester.com/ANFN30711